# How to efficiently SUM and SUBTRACT from two conditionally linked tables using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Is there a more efficient solution for the below query. I have tried to research the topic to the best of my ability but it's difficult to know what to actually search for...

```
$tenant_balance = 0;

$total_charge_amount_query = mysqli_query($con, "
    SELECT  tenant_charge_id, tenant_charge_total_amount
        FROM  accounts_tenant_charge
        WHERE  tenant_charge_tenancy_id='{$tenancy_details['tenancy_id']}'"
     ) or die(mysql_error());  

while($total_charge_amount_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $total_charge_amount_query )) {

    $tenant_balance = $tenant_balance +  $total_charge_amount_row['tenant_charge_total_amount'];

    $total_payment_amount_query = mysqli_query($con, "
        SELECT  tenant_charge_payment_amount
            FROM  accounts_tenant_charge_payment
            WHERE  tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id =
                    '{$total_charge_amount_row['tenant_charge_id']}"
                 ) or die(mysql_error());

    while($total_payment_amount_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $total_payment_amount_query )) {

        $tenant_balance = $tenant_balance - $total_payment_amount_row['tenant_charge_payment_amount'];

    }
}

echo '&pound;' . number_format($tenant_balance, 2, '.', ',');
```

I have added the database table structure and some data below.

Table #1

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jun 16, 2015 at 01:50 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.73-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.4.23

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `propsyst_atlas`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts_tenant_charge`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts_tenant_charge` (
  `tenant_charge_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tenant_charge_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_payment_terms` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_tenancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `tenant_charge_total_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_date_created` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_date_updated` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tenant_charge_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `accounts_tenant_charge`
--

INSERT INTO `accounts_tenant_charge` (`tenant_charge_id`, `tenant_charge_date`, `tenant_charge_payment_terms`, `tenant_charge_tenancy_id`, `tenant_charge_notes`, `tenant_charge_total_amount`, `tenant_charge_date_created`, `tenant_charge_date_updated`, `tenant_charge_created_by`, `tenant_charge_updated_by`) VALUES
(15, '2015-06-22', 1, 25, '', '180.00', '2015-06-14', '2015-06-14', 1, 1),
(14, '2015-06-15', 1, 25, '', '550.00', '2015-06-14', '2015-06-14', 1, 1),
(16, '2015-06-27', 1, 25, '', '10.00', '2015-06-14', '2015-06-14', 1, 1);
```

Table #2

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jun 16, 2015 at 01:51 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.73-cll
-- PHP Version: 5.4.23

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `propsyst_atlas`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `accounts_tenant_charge_payment`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts_tenant_charge_payment` (
  `tenant_charge_payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tenant_charge_payment_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_payment_amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_payment_method` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_payment_notes` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
  `tenant_charge_payment_date_created` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_payment_date_updated` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_payment_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_charge_payment_updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tenant_charge_payment_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `accounts_tenant_charge_payment`
--

INSERT INTO `accounts_tenant_charge_payment` (`tenant_charge_payment_id`, `tenant_charge_payment_date`, `tenant_charge_payment_amount`, `tenant_charge_payment_method`, `tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id`, `tenant_charge_payment_notes`, `tenant_charge_payment_date_created`, `tenant_charge_payment_date_updated`, `tenant_charge_payment_created_by`, `tenant_charge_payment_updated_by`) VALUES
(9, '2015-06-15', '550.00', 2, 14, '', '2015-06-14', '2015-06-14', 1, 1),
(10, '2015-06-22', '50.00', 2, 15, '', '2015-06-16', '2015-06-16', 1, 1);
```

Comment: could you provide sql tables structure? I can guess from the queries but still it can help to simplify the question.

Comment: Yes, what would be the best/easiest way for me to provide my table structures? A screenshot of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: export the structure instead of data, then paste the CREATE TABLE script here

Comment: Or a screenshot would also do..

Comment: I am sure there is a more efficient solution.

Comment: I've added the table info as requested, thanks

Comment: It depends on the number of rows returned by the queries. For small result sets, combining all the queries into a single big query (with sub-queries, `UNION`s etc) probably runs faster because it saves time on network communication. For large result sets it is better to keep it as is. The generation of a big result set (especially for `UNION`s and nested queries) usually requires the creation of a temporary table to store the data and the small amount of time saved on the network communication is overwhelmed by the time used to prepare the big result set (accessing the storage medium).

Comment: @axiac Thank you, it will be a large result set

Comment: @axiac I disagree. looping through resultsets to issue queries will be always worse than a single big query. you are forcing the transfer of all data to the client and preventing optimization at the server.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the point is to get rid of several queries and two PHP loops. With no need for loops, this query the calculate the total charge, payments and balance in one SQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    tenant_charge_tenancy_id,
    sum(tenant_charge_total_amount) as charge,
    IFNULL(sum(payments.payment), 0) as payment,
    sum(tenant_charge_total_amount) - IFNULL(sum(payments.payment), 0) as balance
FROM accounts_tenant_charge
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT
        tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id,
        sum(tenant_charge_payment_amount) as payment
    FROM accounts_tenant_charge_payment
    GROUP BY tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id
) as payments ON tenant_charge_id = tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id
WHERE tenant_charge_tenancy_id= 25
GROUP BY tenant_charge_tenancy_id
```

Instead of 25 you can put the `$tenancy_details['tenancy_id']` in your PHP code. By removing the `WHERE tenant_charge_tenancy_id= ...` You can use this query to fetch all balances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately your code won't work as there can be more than one tenant charge payment to each tenant charge. E.g. a tenant charge could be for £100 but there could be two payments to pay it, say £25 and £75.

Comment: It sums over all payments related to a `tenant_charge_tenancy_id` or `tenancy_id`. I fixed a bug by `IFNULL`. Try it again.

Comment: remove the `WHERE` line and try the query in your phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Oh I think I see the problem now. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you are querying rows from account_tenant_charge with an id, like this

```
SELECT tenant_charge_id, tenant_charge_total_amount
  FROM accounts_tenant_charge
 WHERE tenant_charge_tenancy_id= ?
```

then for each row returned of that query, summing tenant_charge_total_amount in `$tenant_balance`, and querying (with each `tenant_charge_id`)

```
SELECT tenant_charge_payment_amount 
  FROM accounts_tenant_charge_payment 
 WHERE tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id= ?
```

subtracting each tenant_charge_payment_amount from `$tenant_balance`.

First of all, you can do that with a single query that will be compiled once and executed on the server to provide a single result, preventing issuing a lot of queries that must be compiled and executed sequentially and transferring data back and forth between the web server and the dbms just to calculate a single result.

It'd be something like this

```
SELECT SUM(x.amount)
  FROM (SELECT tenant_charge_total_amount amount
          FROM accounts_tenant_charge
         WHERE tenant_charge_tenancy_id= ?
        UNION
        SELECT -tenant_charge_payment_amount amount
          FROM accounts_tenant_charge a
               JOIN accounts_tenant_charge_payment b
               ON tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id = a.tenant_charge_id
         WHERE tenant_charge_tenancy_id= ?) x
```

Second, use bind variables and prepared statements ([see here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)). If you build a dynamic query with each different id, you are forcing the db to compile the query each time, adding overhead to the execution time. Also dynamic queries are susceptible to sql injection attacks.

SQL is a declarative language, which means that you specify *what* you want to get and the dbms will execute it in the best way it finds. You should first rely on the db engine to optimize your queries. Looping through resultsets to issue repeating queries will most probably prevent the engine from optimizing and will add a lot of preventable overhead.

See [DEMO here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39d025/2).

Comment: Does your code allow for multiple payments against the same tenant charge? I haven't had chance to test it yet and am struggling to understand the code (my fault - not yours)

Comment: that's the second part of the union. you can try it in the DEMO link.

Comment: the question marks represent the bind variables you should pass. you can replace them with a number to test it.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns all `tenant_charge_id` and lists the total amount that needs to be paid as well as the total amount that has been paid already.

```
SELECT
    charge.tenant_charge_id,
    charge.tenant_charge_total_amount,
    SUM(payment.tenant_charge_payment_amount) total_payments
FROM  accounts_tenant_charge charge
LEFT JOIN accounts_tenant_charge_payment payment
    ON payment.tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id = charge.tenant_charge_id
GROUP BY tenant_charge_id
```

You could add a `WHERE` clause to restrict the search for only a subset of tenants.

[image: The result based on the data from the question]

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id, SUM(amount) balance
FROM (
   SELECT tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id, tenant_charge_total_amount amount
   FROM accounts_tenant_charge 
   WHERE tenant_charge_tenancy_id='" . $tenancy_details['tenancy_id'] . "'   
   UNION
   SELECT tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id, CONCAT('-',tenant_charge_payment_amount) amount
   FROM accounts_tenant_charge_payment 
   WHERE tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id='" . $total_charge_amount_row['tenant_charge_id'] . "'
) temp
GROUP BY tenant_charge_payment_tenant_charge_id
```

Comment: Should this be a UNION ALL?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you please explain how this is a more efficient solution?